# How can I apply remote force in Pro/E

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, modeling, simulation

I am a beginner in ProE and simulation. I would like to apply force in ProE simulation like below picture.

[image]

Could anyone explain how to put the payload on a remote point?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to apply a moment? Why else would you be applying a force that isn't touching your model?

Comment: My concern is to find a ProE function corresponding to ansys remote force.